# CSS Transparent 1x1 black pixel, not transparent?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get an element that has a 70% transparent black background, and of course I have to resort to using a pixel due to browser compatibility issues. I would just use CSS; however, that makes the entire content of the element transparent also.

Here is the picture:

[image: http://puu.sh/5E7u5.png]

Any idea as to why the pixel isn't transparent? I've created the PNG image in Paint.NET and set the transparency accordingly.

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @JamesMohler Google Chrome

Comment: Perhaps it is not saving it as a png-32, but a png-8 or 24 bit? (Which would lose the alpha transparency.)

Comment: @ScottS That was the problem! Thank you. :)

Comment: @user3029571: Great. I added it as an answer then. I could not before because I had no way of knowing for sure that was the issue you faced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);` where 0.48 is the opacity.

Here a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jimmylovecraft/U78bk/

Comment: Per the OP's concern, note the browser compatibility of using CSS3 colors: http://caniuse.com/css3-colors

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `png` is saved as a 32-bit version to preserve alpha transparency. If it is saving as 8-bit or 24-bit, you will not see it.